# How to hit a file from browser running inside Kubernetes pod?

Tags: html, kubernetes

I have a html file which I want to deploy in Kubernetes. How can I hit that `index.html` from a browser outside the cloud?

Comment: This question needs a HUGE amount of more detail before anybody can start to help. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69447029/edit) the question to include what research you have done, what you've tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: @hardillb The question is very simple.

Comment: The question may be, but the answer won't be, so without the detail any answer given will be lacking so many things as to be near useless

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yeah below answers suggest that I have to run a server. We just have a bunch of static https file that we wanted to deploy in Kubernetes pod. But it seems I'll have to run a server and open http which requires some efforts that I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

You can serve statics like this using a web server and run it in a pod. (Apache, NGINX etc.) You'd then create a service for this pod and ideally use an Ingress resource to finally expose it publicly.(You could also use a service with type `LoadBalancer`) Please check [K8S Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [K8S Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

**The only correct answer to your opinion based question in this way will be - it depends.**

I will show you a few ways how it looks in general and highlight where there may be discrepancies.
First, you need to set up a cluster. You can do it locally, e.g. using [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), or in the cloud ([AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) etc.) Bare in mind, that you should not use Minikube in production.

The next step will be the deployment pod of the http server. It can be for example [Apache](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-static-content-apache-kubernetes/). Another dependencies.

Additionally, if you want your http server to be visible from the outside, you need to create a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and then expose it to the outside world. There are also many types of them, so check the documentation before doing anything. Additionally, you will probably need a database etc.

However, if you want to manage traffic, you can use an ingress solution.

Take into account that there are different types of them on the market (not counting built-in solutions in clouds):

- [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)
- [Ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)
- [F5 Nginx ingress controller](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-ingress-controller/)

In a more advanced configuration, you can use a service mesh, e.g. [istio](https://istio.io/).

Other solution will be using Helm. [Here is one of the guides](https://bitnami.com/stack/apache/helm).